# postgres: can I prepare unnamed statement from SQL

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html
next to `PQprepare`:

> The function creates a prepared statement named *stmtName* from the
>   query string, which must contain a single SQL command. *stmtName* can be
>   "" to create an unnamed statement, in which case any pre-existing
>   unnamed statement is automatically replaced; otherwise it is an error
>   if the statement name is already defined in the current session.

and further:

> Prepared statements for use with *PQexecPrepared* can also be created by
>   executing SQL `PREPARE` statements.

now https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

> PREPARE name [ ( data_type [, ...] ) ] AS statement

and:

> name An arbitrary name given to this particular prepared statement. It
>   must be unique within a single session and is subsequently used to
>   execute or deallocate a previously prepared statement.

**Question:**
Can I not create unnamed prepared statement using SQL statement `PREPARE`? silently reusable and all the rest...

```
t=# prepare ""(int) as select $1,now();
ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: prepare ""(int) as select $1,now();
```

and ommiting the name:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
```

Or I'm missing something very obvious?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Unnamed prepared statements are only supported on the wire protocol.

They're mainly used for one-shot statements with bind parameters, and for batching.

Comment: thank you. I thought so. do you think I should ask docs people to adjust `Prepared statements for use with PQexecPrepared can also be created by executing SQL PREPARE statements.` to have this exception?..

Comment: If you think it necessary, sure. Submit a patch :)